# Formatting Html Tables in R - Using Css

Tags: html, css, r

I am using the package "htmlTable" in R and trying to format a table.  Specifically, I want to delete the uppermost border and change the remaining borders to black. Please run the code below to get the table that I am looking at.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
devtools::install_github('SwedishPensionsAgency/format.tables')
library(htmlTable)

Code <- ("AB", "BC", "MB", "NB")
Numbers <- c(148137, 186955, 37755, 17376)
DataFrame <- data.frame(Code, Numbers, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


htmlTable(DataFrame, align = "c",
      rnames = FALSE,
      caption = "<b> <center> <font face = Times New Roman> Table 1. Test  <br> <br>",
      tfoot = "<b> Source </b> <br> [1]  Test Source",
      header = paste(c(" Territory", "Number of People")),
      css.caption = "color:red;",
      col.rgroup = c("none", "#ADADAD"),
      padding.tspanner = "", ctable = TRUE,
      css.table = "width:150%;border: none")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know basic CSS, you can easily format any element in the table quite easily:

```
x <- htmlTable(DataFrame, align = "c",
      rnames = FALSE,
      caption = "<b> <center> <font face = Times New Roman> Table 1. Test  <br> <br>",
      tfoot = "<b> Source </b> <br> [1]  Test Source",
      header = paste(c(" Territory", "Number of People")),
      css.caption = "color:red;",
      col.rgroup = c("none", "#ADADAD"),
      padding.tspanner = "", ctable = TRUE)


## add id to gmisc_table
x <- gsub('(?<=.gmisc_table.)', ' id = \'gmisc_table\'', x, perl = TRUE)
formats <- paste(x)
attributes(formats) <- attributes(x)

## Edit css
css <- '
<style>
/* Remove the top border */
#gmisc_table > thead > tr > th {
  border-top: none !important;
}

/* Add boarder to the table body */
#gmisc_table > tbody > tr > td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>'

gsub('^', css, formats)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the methods you are using to generate the `<html>` is limiting your options for formatting. Below is my suggestion to how you should do this if you want absolute control of the styling. It also allows you to use resources like [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com) to fix perfect formatting:

Your data:

```
Code <- c("AB", "BC", "MB", "NB")
Numbers <- c(148137, 186955, 37755, 17376)
DataFrame <- data.frame(Code, Numbers, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(DataFrame) <- c("Territory", "Number of People")
```

I use this library to produce `<html>` tables. Not as few lines of code
as yours but no lack of flexibility. Here I install using the
`remotes` package:

```
remotes::install_github('trosendal/hlt')
library(hlt)
```

Basic table structure and add style:

```
my_table <- hlt::html_table(DataFrame)
hlt::tag_attr(my_table) <- list(id = "table1", class = "gmisc_table")
```

A blurb before and after your table:

```
a <- html_p("Table 1. Test")
b <- html_p("<b>Source</b><br>[1] Test Source")
```

Put the table in a `<div>` as you had:

```
my_table <- hlt::html_div(a +
                          my_table +
                          b)
hlt::tag_attr(my_table) <- list(style = "margin: 0 auto; display: table; margin-top: 1em;")
```

Add the style (same as yours, plus your suggested changes)

```
head <- hlt::html_head(hlt::html_meta(charset="utf-8") +
                       hlt::html_meta("http-equiv" = "Content-type") +
                       hlt::html_meta("content" = "text/html") +
                       hlt::html_style(c(".gmisc_table {",
                                         "    width:150%;",
                                         "    border:1px solid black;",
                                         "    border-collapse:collapse",
                                         "}",
                                         ".gmisc_table th {",
                                         "    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;",
                                         "    border-left: 1px solid black;",
                                         "    text-align: center;",
                                         "}",
                                         ".gmisc_table tr:nth-child(even) {",
                                         "    background-color: #adadad;",
                                         "}",
                                         ".gmisc_table tr:nth-child(odd) {",
                                         "    background-color: transparent;",
                                         "}",
                                         ".gmisc_table td {",
                                         "    background-color: transparent;",
                                         "    text-align: center;",
                                         "    border-left: 1px solid black",
                                         "}")))
```

Stitch the pieces together into a page:

```
page <- hlt::html_html(head +
                       hlt::html_body(my_table))
tab <- tempfile()
capture.output(file = tab, print(page))
browseURL(tab)
```

It's not clear exactly how you wanted the final formatting of
the table to be; I removed the top line and added all black solid
borders otherwise. But from this, I hope it illustrates how this
method provides all the flexibility you could ever need. I started
with the htmlTable package too for making tables on [sva.se](https://www.sva.se)
and quickly found that the needs are always more complex than the
features in R packages that write html.